# SmartGwt causes exception in dev mode when I have separate gwt module for view objects

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee, smartgwt, gwt-platform

Kindly guide me to resolve following issue.

I have created a separate GWT module for view entities entities.

Following is the structure of my project:

**gwt-application :** (Presentation related code resides here and I have used GWT-Platform and SmartGwt)

**gwt-commons-entities :** (GWT Module : This will contain entities to be shared between gwt-applicaiton gwt-service-layer)

**gwt-service-layer :** (Will contain business logic of the application)

I am facing following exception when I run this application in dev mode (Eclipse -> Run As -> Web Application):

```
(UnknownFileName:-1) 2012-03-26 14:30:47,069 [FATAL] Uncaught Exception:
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null): null
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am not getting such exception when I have my entities in gwt-application.

But I will have to make big architectural changes to my application so I have to put view entities in separate module so that it can be shared.

Appreciate for any clues.

Comment: To make the problem simpler, let say we have a User.java I would use as a transfer object which implements Serializable interface. I have separate projects for service layer and presentation layer so I have to make User.java sharable so I have created new maven project just for transfer objects which will archived as GWT module, similar to smartgwt.jar. I will inherit this module in my gwt project's *.gwt.xml file. So In such configuration I am getting this exception when I run application in dev mode and not getting it deployed a war of the project in tomcat. All projects are maven projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha. Forgot to call toString() for grid's attribute value. Strange thing observed here it throws above mentioned exception in dev mode however it works fine if generated war of GWT application is deployed in tomcat. GWT caused big pain and cost me 3 days to resolve this.

Comment: Explain more please. I've got similar problem: `com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null): null
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)` 

when i'm saving record with my custom datasource and I call  `processResponse(dsRequest.getRequestId(), response);`

Comment: Such issues also occur in situations like if you are adding value in a Grid/Tree where column expects string value and you try to pass value of other type.